# Find what customer has spent the most money across multiple payments

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So I have a model called Purchases and I need to find who are the top paying customers by adding up all there payments.

The method I currently have is rather retarded and I know it can be shrunk massively, what would be the best method for this?

For example:

```
class Purchases(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
    username = models.CharField("Username", max_length=50)
```

I need to query this model which for instance has 12 entries all belonging to Customer1, Customer2 and Customer3

- Customer1 has 4 separate payments that total to £100
- Customer2 has 2 separate payments that total to £75
- Customer3 has 6 separate payments that total to £300

I need to find the customer that has spent to most in this example it would be customer3 with a total spent value of £300.

Here is a code example that I just came up with but I know it can be improved big time:

```
def find_top_customer(self)
    top_donor = None
    spent = None
    for customer in Purchase.objects.filter(marketid=self.marketid):
        customer_spent = Purchase.objects.filter(marketid=self.marketid,username=customer.username).aggregate('price')[0]
        if customer_spent > spent:
            top_donor = customer.username
            spent = customer_spent
```

Comment: you need to provide much more information. show us what you have now, sample input/table, and what you'd like the output to look like.

Comment: If you have working code I would consider taking it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the code I have is rather ugly and I would rather not share it, it makes me feel really bad lol.

Comment: @SamBuckingham No reason to be ashamed it is how we all must learn.

Comment: @user2097159 I wouldn't normally be, but I know this is a rather simple solution but I just cant seem to figure it out and I think my example would just make things harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out, sorry for bad answers... (code tested)

If you have a Foreign Key to user in your Purchase Model :

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='purchase_set')
```

You can get the most purchasing User by this way :

```
from django.db.models import Sum
most_purchasing_user = User.objects.annotate(purchase_sum=Sum('purchase_set__price')).order_by('-purchase_sum')[0]
```

**Explanation :** 
For all user we aggregate theire purchase_set and do the Sum of purchase prices, then we order_by the biggest purchase_set sum, and get the first with [0]

**Warning**
This is a big cost to the database, you should consider to pu the result in cache
[Django Cache Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/)

Comment: That's a brilliant answer, I knew I would have to use aggregate, but I forgot about order and indexing.

Comment: However Is there any way I could remove the forloop? so instead of having to loop through each customer?

Comment: The ordering by price is not needed, I want the total of all the prices not the highest.

Comment: Updated my answere with working and tested solution... sorry for bad answeres

Comment: Thank you your answer was perfect, I knew it could be simplified massively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should def some functions like:

```
allPurchases(client)
findPurchase(id, client)
```

and play with these to get the data you want.

Comment: This really was not helpful at all.